# I'm trying to create a program in python that takes the input the user gives and tells them if they're underage or not

Tags: python, if-statement, statements

I'm new to python and this is what i came up with, it does not work.

```
age = input("How old are you? ")

if age < 18
    print("You are under age.")
else
    print("You are over age")
```

Thanks.

Comment: `input()` returns string. cast it to an integer: `age = int(input("How old are you? "))`

Comment: in addition to https://stackoverflow.com/users/10035985/andrej-kesely 's comment, you are missing colons after your `if` and `else`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. This code will have produced a _useful error message_ that you have not included here. Please _always **read** and **share** error messages_. They're not there for fun; they are actually helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the `input` function must be convert to an `int` by using the `int` constructor, like `int("123")` in order to be compared to the number `18`.

```
if int(input("How old are you?")) < 18:
  print("You are under age")
else:
  print("You are over age")
```

Comment: thank you very much! so it turns out i need to put an int before the input because the answer i want is a number right? i also forgot the :

Comment: @LucasBarbieri Correct.

Answer (score 1):

What is the type of `input`? Hmm let's open the REPL and see.

```
$ ipython
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.6.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: age = input('how old are you?')
how old are you?10

In [2]: type(age)
Out[2]: str

In [5]: age == '10'
Out[5]: True

In [6]: age == 10
Out[6]: False
```

See how Python treats the type `str` different from `int`?

You're also forgetting colons `:` after your `if statememt`